# Show that the following is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Let (X,d) be a metric space with disjoint, nonempty, closed subsets $A,B \subset X$.

Show that the function $V: X \to [0,1]$ defined by

$$V(x) = \frac{\operatorname{dist}(x,A)}{\operatorname{dist}(x,A) + \operatorname{dist}(x,B)}$$

is continuous. Then prove that any connected metric space containing at least two points is uncountable.

I'm kind of in the process of staring and not sure how to start. I'm thinking that I need to use the triangle inequality somehow to put $\delta$ in. Like I know I have $|x - y| < \delta$, so if I only examine the numerator (for example) and I say $d(x,y) \leq d(x,A) + d(y,A)$, then I could plug delta in. I'm not sure how to get to there though as the denominator would become quite complicated. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $V=f\circ g$, where $g:X\to [0,\infty)^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ is given by $x\mapsto (d(x,A),d(x,B))$ and $f$ is given by $(s,t)\mapsto \frac{s}{s+t}$. Now, $g$ is continuous by the basic properties of metric spaces and $f$ is continuous by basic real analysis. Hence, $V$ is continuous.

Indeed, $g$ maps $X$ into $[0,\infty)^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and closed. To see this, note that $d(x,A)=0$ implies $x\in A$, since $A$ is closed, which then implies that $x\not \in B$, which implies that $d(x,B)>0$, since $B$ is closed.

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for the reply! Could you possibly clarify the notation a little bit? The way you defined g and f seems a bit unclear to me. The mappings and the s,t seem to come out of no where. Also, how did you recognize that V = f o g? In case if I get a similar problem on a test, I'd like to know how to recognize that.

Comment: What do you mean come out of nowhere? It's just recognising that your function has something in the numerator and that same something plus another something in the denominator. Well, the map that takes something and another thing and produces that fraction is certainly continuous everywhere it's defined, so if something and another thing are both continuous, then the map will be continuous all in all. It's just breaking the proof of continuity down into smaller, more manageable steps. If you're really lucky, as in this case, you'll end with something you already know to be continuous.

Comment: I mean... the $s$ and $t$ are just letters I chose to use. They don't mean anything.

Comment: Ok I got it. I see what you mean now. I just did not recognize that nor did I think to break it into two continuous functions and use composition. Glad I know that now!

Comment: @DominicBlanco I mean... if you wanna go the other route, I guess the most basic proof goes via noting that $V(x)-V(y)= \frac{d(x,A)(d(y,A)+d(y,B))-d(y,A)(d(x,A)+d(x,B))}{(d(x,A)+d(x,B))(d(y,A)+d(y,B))}=\frac{d(x,A)d(y,B)-d(y,A)d(x,B)}{(d(x,A)+d(x,B))(d(y,A)+d(y,B))}$ and then use closedness and disjointedness of $A$ and $B$ to give a local lower bound on $d(x,A)+d(x,B)$ and at that point it becomes manageable. It's just also pretty tedious to write out.

Comment: that seems a lot more complicated though. I like your way, I just didn't see it when I first looked at the problem. It makes sense now though. It is good to know that way will work as well!